# Sum when array contains the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a noob in JS and would like to solve this problem:

I've got two arrays with corresponding data. One array contains a date and the second array contains a value corresponding with that specific date:

`dates = [2020-03-01,2020-03-01,2020-03-01,2020-03-02,2020-03-03]` 
`cases= [0,1,5,6,2]`

I would want to output an array that contains each date **once** with the sum of the cases from that date.

Output in this example would be: 
`2020-03-01 - 6` 
`2020-03-02 - 6` 
`2020-03-03 - 2`

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how i'd go about solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes I see now, ithe dates are meant to be strings

["2020-03-01","'2020-03-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-02","2020-03-03"]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing both arrays have the same length, I would create an object whose keys are the dates and whose values are the sum of each date:

```js
const dates = ["2020-03-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-02","2020-03-03"]
const cases= [0,1,5,6,2]

const datesSumm = {}; // change name of variable

dates.forEach((date, index) => datesSumm[date] ? datesSumm[date] += cases[index] : datesSumm[date] = cases[index])

console.log(datesSumm)

const expectedOutput = Object.entries(datesSumm).reduce((acc, el) => `${acc}${el[0]} - ${el[1]}\n`, "")

console.log(expectedOutput)
```

`?` Is the ternary operator, its the same as an `if...else` clause. It checks if the object with that key already exists so it sums to whatever value it has with the new one and if it doesn't, it sets directly that value to the object property.

#### Why couldn't you just do `datesSumm[date] += cases[index]`?

Because if `datesSumm[date]` doesn't exist then it`s value is` undefined`and you can't add other number to undefined because it will return NaN since` +undefined`(coercing to number`undefined`) returns it =>` NaN + ANumber = NaN`.

Comment: Could you explain why you are using the ? operator in your example?

Comment: Yes! It's the ternary operator, its the same as an `if...else` clause. It checks if the object with that key already exists so it sums to whatever value it has with the new one and if it doesn't, it sets directly that value to the object property. Explaining more in the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

This will output in exactly the format you requested

```js
dates = ['2020-03-01','2020-03-01','2020-03-01','2020-03-02','2020-03-03'];
cases= [0,1,5,6,2]
results = [...dates.reduce((a, d, i) => (a.set(d, (a.get(d) || 0) + cases[i]),a), new Map).entries()].map(v => v.join(' - ')).join('\n');
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map to create an object array (id and value) and then use reduce to sum them up by id.

run snippet below

```js
const dates = ['2020-03-01',
  '2020-03-01',
  '2020-03-01',
  '2020-03-02',
  '2020-03-03'
];
const cases = [0, 1, 5, 6, 2];



var result = [];
dates.map(
  (element, index) => ({
    Id: element,
    qty: cases[index]
  }),
).reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.Id]) {
    res[value.Id] = {
      Id: value.Id,
      qty: 0
    };
    result.push(res[value.Id])
  }
  res[value.Id].qty += value.qty;
  return res;
}, {});



console.log(result);
```